# Whats the difference between ($test) = (@test); and $test = @test; in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
($test) = (@test);
$test = @test;
```

With one bracket around the variable it acesses the first element of the array. I cant find any info on what the bracket around the array does.

Comment: See [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ```
> ($test) = (@test);
> ```

This assigns the values inside of `@test` to a list of variables that only contains `$test`. So `$test` will contain the first element of `@test`. That's called *list context*. You can also leave out the parenthesis around `@test`.

```
my @test = ('a', 'b');
my ($test) = @test;    # 'a'
```

This is also very commonly used to assign the parameters of functions to variables. The following will assign the first three arguments to the function and ignore any other arguments that follow.

```
sub foo {
    my ($self, $foo, $bar) = @_;

    # ...
}
```

You can also skip elements in the middle. This is also valid. The `bar` value will not get assigned here.

```
my @foo = qw(foo bar baz);
(my $foo, undef, my $baz) = @foo;
```

---

> ```
> $test = @test;
> ```

This forces `@test` into *scalar context*. Arrays in scalar context return the number of elements, so `$test` will become an integer.

```
my @test = ('a', 'b');
my $test = @test;      # 2
```

---

You can read more about context in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context).

Comment: It might be added that this is not a fluke: many Perl expressions return different results depending on whether they are in list context or not.  E.g. this is why `my $match = $var =~ /con(.*)text/` won't give you the value of `$1` in `$match` whereas `my ($match) = $var =~ /con(.*)text/` will.